# I need to get the QRCode plugin for Grails to work in 2.0.0

Tags: grails, plugins, qr-code, zxing

I'm having an issue with the QR Code plugin (which uses the ZXing libraries - something I have used before with great success in Android and Java) working in a project I'm doing.

I've installed the plugin, but all I get when I try using any variant of the `<qrcode:...>` tag in a GSP page is that is gets replaced with `<call />` in my HTML code.

I can't seem to get any sort of debugging info for the plugin either, although I might be doing it wrong.  I tried adding `debug 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.qrcode'` to the log4j section of Config.groovy - which seemed right... but to be fair it was a bit of a guess just based on the plugins location in the file structure...

Does anyone have any pointers that might help?

Cheers

Steve

*[edit]*

If I turn on debug-level logging for everything I do get the following three lines that relate to the plugin - but it just appears to be locating the actual file locations for the plugin rather than actually using it:

```
pages.GroovyPageResourceLoader Resolved GSP location [/grails-app/views/plugins/qrcode-0.1/grails-app/views/layouts/home.gsp] to resource [URL [file:C:/repo/grails-app/views/plugins/qrcode-0.1/grails-app/views/layouts/home.gsp]] (exists? [false]) using base resource [URL [file:C:/repo/]]    
pages.GroovyPageResourceLoader Resolved GSP location [/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/plugins/qrcode-0.1/grails-app/views/layouts/home.gsp] to resource [URL [file:C:/repo/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/plugins/qrcode-0.1/grails-app/views/layouts/home.gsp]] (exists? [false]) using base resource [URL [file:C:/repo/]]    
pages.GroovyPageResourceLoader Resolved GSP location [/plugins/qrcode-0.1/grails-app/views/layouts/home.gsp] to resource [URL [file:C:/repo/plugins/qrcode-0.1/grails-app/views/layouts/home.gsp]] (exists? [false]) using base resource [URL [file:C:/repo/]]
```

*[edit #2]*

I've been looking into the lines above and noticed that the views that its looking for do not exist.  The plugin only has a controller and a taglib folder... I'm really not up with plugin creation, so I don't really know why its looking for this... but I will do some reading and see if I can make sense of that.

Comment: have you tried it in Grails version 1.3.7 or version 2.0.1 ? It might be a bug with this version of Grails

Comment: No, I haven't tried going back to 1.3.7, and as for 2.0.1, I have a release deadline in about 24 hours... I'll branch it and try upgrading it after that.  For now I've just done QR codes manually in a service, and its working fine.